Input should accept only numbers LWC Salesforce
My requirement is that user can only enter the number.
I have tried both LWC lightning-input type number and HTML input type number and used pattern and min value 0 as well but still I am able to enter - (negative) + (positive) and . (dot) values in input box.
<lightning-input type="number" name="input1" label="Enter a number" ></lightning-input>
<input type="number" min="0" >
examples -99
+99
10.99
but my requirement is user can enter only numbers like 99 1099
Please help me on how to allow the user to enter only numbers.

When you say it's not working, what's happening?  the lightning-input should do this using min and step.  the user will be able to enter invalid data, but an error should appear on blur

This question is similar to: lightning-input should accept numbers only in lwc. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I have tried min and step but I am able to enter - negative value. My requirement is that user can only enter numbers. @TusharJadav yes, it's different because I am asking about the HTML input as well.

Use a lightning-input of type text with the pattern attribute. This lets you specify a validation RegEx like \d* that will only accept between 0 and unlimited digits.
<lightning-input
    type="text"
    label="Enter a number"
    pattern="\d*"
></lightning-input>


Thank you for your answer. I have tried pattern="\d*" with type text but unfortunately it's not working. Any other recommendations would be useful.

Ok, I realize that I doesn't prevent the input of non-digits but it marks the field as invalid if there's anything other than digits. You can then check for the validity property value when the user attempts to submit the form.

If you specify min="0" and type="number"` your component will validate the input, but not prevent the user from typing wrongful information in it.
Your requirement is simply not achievable with the current state of lightning-input. You will want to look at validating your user's input before submission instead. Check the "Input Validation" section of the lightning-input Documentation tab.
